# What is the fastest way to draw circles in python and save as png?

Tags: performance, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, png

### Background

I'm optimizing a project.

Profiling the code I found that 50% of the time is spend on a function in which a set of circles (different radii, colors and locations) are drawn to a choosen sector of fixed size (white canvas) if their center corrdinates is within the sector bounds. Depending on the usage the function saves the figure as a png and returns the path or returns the image as an numpy array.

The `build-in method matplotlib._png.write_png` from `savefig` is the most expensive But there is also some overhead from creating the figures, etc.

Generally the code is used with multiprocessing / parallel programming.

### Example output

[image: Image with circles.]

### Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os

    def get_top_view(sector, circles, file_path, save_image_flag):

        # get the sector bounds. 
        x_low, y_low, x_high, y_high = get_sector_bounds(sector)

        # init figure
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.set_xlim(y_low, y_high)
        ax.set_ylim(x_low, x_high)
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        ax.axis('off')

        # c is a circle object with all relevant data (center coordinates,
        # radius, RGB color tuple)
        for c in circles:
           if x_low <= c.x_coord <= x_high and y_low <= c.y_coord <= y_high:
                    shape = plt.Circle((c.x_coord, c.y_coord), c.radius, color=c.color)
                    shape_plot = ax.add_artist(shape)
                    shapes.append(shape_plot)
        plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
        if save_image_flag:
            plt.savefig(file_path + '_cc.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.02)
            plt.close()
            return file_path
        else:
            ax.margins(0)
            fig.tight_layout()
            fig.canvas.draw()
            image_from_plot = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
            image_from_plot = image_from_plot.reshape(
                                fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
            image_from_plot = image_from_plot[:, 13:-14]
            resized = cv2.resize(image_from_plot, (499, 391))
            cropped = resized[78:-78]
            plt.close()
            return cropped
```

### Questions

There is the issue that the array version and the png image is slightly different. I think that relates to the DPI of the image. I want to fix that and I'm thinking about different options who to speedup this function.

1. Speedup the process and keeping matplotlib, similar to this [example from Github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12913#issuecomment-443308122).
2. Get rid of matplotlib and draw it with Pillow, e.g. some thing like:

   ```
   from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

   def get_top_view(sector, circles, file_path, save_image_flag):

       # get the sector bounds. 
       x_low, y_low, x_high, y_high = get_sector_bounds(sector)

       im = Image.new('RGB', (499, 235), (255, 255, 255))
       draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

       # there needs to be some rescaling that the corrdinates match which
       # I don't account for at the moment. 
       for c in circles:
              if x_low <= c.x_coord <= x_high and y_low <= c.y_coord <= y_high:
                    draw.ellipse((c.x_coord - c.radius, c.y_coord - c.radius,
                                  c.x_coord + c.radius, c.y_coord + c.radius), 
                                  fill=c.color)

       if save_image_flag:
           im.save(file_path + '.png')
           return file_path

       else:
           image_as_array = convert_to_array()  # have to think about how I'll do that
           return image_as_array
   ```
3. A different approach that is faster (and somehow convenient)...

I'd be glad for any feedback on the two issues.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information to answer you. You seem to want to draw 3? 128? 72,000? circles of radius between 8..30? 12..200? pixels on a white? green? canvas of dimensions ??x?? You mention multiprocessing but there's none in your code and it's unclear how you could split this anyway. You seem to want to be able to save at any point - do you save often? Why do you put `quality=100` on a PNG also? I'm just trying to get you to explain the bits that are missing for me... someone else may be more familiar with what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks for your reply. In one figure there are only a few circles (colored) drawn on a white canvas. Technical, there can be any amout of circles. It represents a simualtion, where the circles grow depending on some update to the underlying model. This itself is running in several processes, thats why the multiprocessing is not part of the example. In practice, about draw 200 circles on about 100 sectors/canvas. However, the whole process is repeated for +100k times. Output size for the png and array is 499x235 (x3). Does that clear things up?

Comment: That helps, thank you. Did you try using OpenCV to draw the circles?

Comment: I haven't tried OpenCV's [circle](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.circle). Do you have an estimate how much faster it might be?

Comment: It generally beats all-comers comfortably, but nothing specific. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my findings here. I'm calling the function 2200 times for each output type  within the simulation framework. All computation is serial as the multiprocessing code is not part of the example.

There are 220 sectors with 200 circles randomly distributed amongst the sectors. The simulation runs for 10 steps, where the circles radii get updated and new figures are drawn. Hence, 2200 calls to the function.

1. To **generate and save png images** it took **293483ms** previously.
2. To **generate numpy arrays** it took **92715ms** previously.

### Speedup with Matplotlib

1. **Generating and saving images** (save_image_flag = True) now takes **126485ms**.
2. **Generating numpy arrays** now takes **57029ms**.

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import os

   def get_top_view(sector, circles, file_path, save_image_flag):

       # get the sector bounds. 
       x_low, y_low, x_high, y_high = get_sector_bounds(sector)

       # init figure
       fig, ax = plt.subplots()
       ax.set_xlim(y_low, y_high)
       ax.set_ylim(x_low, x_high)
       # These were unnecessary 
       # ax.set_yticklabels([])
       # ax.set_xticklabels([])
       # ax.set_yticks([])
       # ax.set_xticks([])
       ax.set_aspect('equal')
       ax.axis('off')

       # c is a circle object with all relevant data (center coordinates,
       # radius, RGB color tuple)
       for c in circles:
          if x_low <= c.x_coord <= x_high and y_low <= c.y_coord <= y_high:
                   shape = plt.Circle((c.x_coord, c.y_coord), c.radius, color=c.color)
                   shape_plot = ax.add_artist(shape)
                   shapes.append(shape_plot)
       plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
       # I added this to get the discrepancies between the generated image and 
       # the numpy array, as bbox_inches='tight' only applies to the saved image.
       bbox0 = fig.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer()).padded(0.02)
       if save_image_flag:
           plt.savefig(file_path + '_cc.png', bbox_inches=bbox0)
           plt.close()
           return file_path
       else:
           buf = io.BytesIO()
           fig.savefig(buf, format="rgba", dpi=100, bbox_inches=bbox0)
           buf.seek(0)
           img = np.reshape(np.frombuffer(buf.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8), 
                            newshape=(235, 499, -1))
           img = img[..., :3]
           buf.close()
           plt.close()
           return image
   ```

### Speedup without Matplotlib

Research is in progress...